# nodeJS couldn't load angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have a problem about nodeJS and I am trying to learn nodeJS and pretty much beginner.

here is the location of the folders :
- application
-- controllers
--- mainController.js
-- lib
--- js
---- angular.min.js
-- views
--- index.html
- routes
- server.js

so i have this server.js and it's running :

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var routes = require('./routes/routes');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/application')); //static path
routes(app);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/application/views/index.html")
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('server started on: ' + port);
```

but angularJS is not loaded in index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing Web</title>    
    <!-- LOAD JS -->
    <script src="../lib/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../controllers/mainController.js"></script>    
</head>    
<body>
{{greetings}}
</body>    
</html>
```

anyone has solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `ng-app` and `ng-controller`? you need to add those to the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="your_module">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing Web</title>    
    <!-- LOAD JS -->
    <script src="../lib/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../controllers/mainController.js"></script>    
</head>    
<body ng-controller="your_ctrl">
{{greetings}}
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: about "your_module" , is it the server.js?